# Excel VBA - Populate a column on one sheet with values from another sheet based on 3 criteria (complicated IF AND related VBA with wildcards)

Tags: vba, excel

I am new at Excel VBA and despite my efforts I cannot seem to find a similar example online to use as a solution to my issue.

I am creating a table of data related to an inventory of automobiles. The workbook that I have set up has two tabs. The first is labeled "FEEDER", and contains a table of hardcoded inputs (automobile values). The second is labeled "Sheet1" and contains raw data for all inventory. Sheet 1 requires automobile values in column "I". My goal is to set the workbook up so that a Column I labeled "Values" within "Sheet1", would be autopopulated with the click of a button from value inputs from the FEEDER sheet. The tricky part (for me) is that the values are based on 1) the automobile type (i.e. sedan/ pickup/ etc.), 2) the color (different colors have slightly different values), and 3) the Manufacture year. I was approaching this at first like an IF AND statement, but thought creating a macro would be a more efficient route to take.

I have a working list, but many more automobile types to go (400+ total). If I could get a some help at thsi stage I can [hopefully] figure out the rest.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Screen Shots here: [FEEDER Table and SHEET1 Inventory List](https://transportcit.box.com/AutoInventoryVBA)

My code:

```
Sub ValueFill()
Dim x As Integer
For x = 3 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & x).Text) = "Pickup*" And UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Text("C" & x).Value) = "Red*" Then
        Range("I" & x).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("FEEDER").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("f" & x), Sheets("Feeder").Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 0), 1)
ElseIf UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & x).Text) = "Pickup*" And UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Text("C" & x).Value) = "Blue*" Then
        Range("I" & x).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("FEEDER").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("f" & x), Sheets("Feeder").Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 0), 1)
ElseIf UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & x).Text) = "Sedan*" And UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Text("C" & x).Value) = "Red*" Then
        Range("I" & x).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("FEEDER").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("f" & x), Sheets("Feeder").Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 0), 1)
ElseIf UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & x).Text) = "Sedan*" And UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Text("C" & x).Value) = "Blue*" Then
        Range("I" & x).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("FEEDER").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("f" & x), Sheets("Feeder").Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 0), 1)

'I would keep "ElseIf-ing" for each combination of auto type and color, then index match by year...

Else: Range("I" & x).Text = "Error"

End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: If you are using wildcards, you need to use `... Like "Pickup*"` and `... Like  "Red*"`.

Comment: a) What is `Sheets("Sheet1").Text("C" & x).Value` intended to reference? b) what worksheet is intended to receive the formulas?

Comment: Do you want to put a formula into the worksheet or resolve the formula result within VBA and put the result value into the worksheet?

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 0):

My knee-jerk reaction is to use two different functions, since color and type are interdependent: one for handling the year and one for handling the type and  color of the vehicle.  Something like

```
Sub ValueFill()
   For car = 1 to last 'this is your loop over the cars in Sheet1
     color = type_color(car)
     year = get_year(car)
     price = Sheets("FEEDER").Cells(year, color).value
Function get_year(car)
     'gets the year value for a give car and returns the corresponding row 
      number of that year, i.e car year 2009 is row 10 in FEEDER
  End Function
Function type_color()
   'will first get the type then convert based on color
   'gets the type of the car and returns the left column index for that type
         'i.e. type = pickup then column index = 3  (Column C)
    if color not same as column value from above then
        offset it
        'i.e. for a blue pickup column index + 1 -> 4
  end function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial rewrite of your sample code. It isn't enough to finalize the module but perhaps it can get you started.

```
Sub ValueFill()
    Dim x As Long, wsf As Worksheet, app As Application

    Set app = Application
    Set wsf = Sheets("FEEDER")

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For x = 3 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Select Case Left(LCase(.Cells(x, 1).Text), 5)
                Case "picku"
                    Select Case Left(LCase(.Cells(x, 3).Text), 3)
                        Case "red"
                            'unclear on whether you want a value or a formula - pick one of these
                            .Range("I" & x).Value = app.Index(wsf.Columns(3), app.Match(.Cells(x, 6).Value, wsf.Columns(2), 0))
                            '.Range("I" & x).Formula = "=INDEX(Feeder!C:C, MATCH(F" & x & ", Feeder!B:B, 0))"
                            '.Range("I" & x).FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(Feeder!C3, MATCH(RC6, Feeder!C2, 0))"
                        Case "blu"
                            .Range("I" & x).Value = app.Index(wsf.Columns(4), app.Match(.Cells(x, 6).Value, wsf.Columns(2), 0))
                        Case Else
                            'do nothing
                    End Select
                Case "sedan"
                    Select Case Left(LCase(.Cells(x, 3).Text), 3)
                        Case "red"
                            .Range("I" & x).Value = app.Index(wsf.Columns(5), app.Match(.Cells(x, 6).Value, wsf.Columns(2), 0))
                        Case "blu"
                            .Range("I" & x).Value = app.Index(wsf.Columns(6), app.Match(.Cells(x, 6).Value, wsf.Columns(2), 0))
                        Case Else
                            'do nothing
                    End Select
                Case Else
                    Debug.Print "not it"
            End Select
        Next x

    End With
    Set wsf = Nothing
    Set app = Nothing

End Sub
```

If more information about the nature of the FEEDER worksheet was provided, a one-size-fits-all formula may be able to be developed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I am not familiar with excel functions. But, I can do it with vba code only.

Thanks, this is very good question. Try it with my idea.

Here, my approach for your problem. You don't need anything to modify. Just copy and run. It work well.

```
Public Sub fillValue()

    Dim inventorySheet, priceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim inventoryRow, priceRow As Integer
    Dim redPickup, bluePickup, redSedan, blueSedan, redRoadster, blueRoadster As String
    Dim automobileType, automobileColor, automobilePrice As String
    Dim isFound As Boolean

    'Set sheet for common use.
    Set inventorySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set priceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FEEDER")

    'Price list in FEEDER sheet are stable.
    'So, we can use them as constant.
    'I initialize them as follow. You can add more column.
    redPickup = "C"
    bluePickup = "D"
    redSedan = "E"
    blueSedan = "F"
    redRoadster = "G"
    blueRoadster = "H"

    'Set the start row Sheet1 sheet
    inventoryRow = 3

    'Looping all data from "Sheet1" sheet.
    'One thing that the main colum is Automobile Type. So, loop until it is blank.
    Do While inventorySheet.Range("A" & inventoryRow) <> ""

        'First, get the price row from FEEDER sheet for manufacture year.

        'Reset flag.
        isFound = False

        'Set the start row of FEEDER sheet.
        priceRow = 4

        'Loop manufacture year column of FEEDER sheet until blank
        Do While priceSheet.Range("B" & priceRow) <> ""

            If priceSheet.Range("B" & priceRow) = inventorySheet.Range("F" & inventoryRow) Then

                'Set true for exist record for manufacture year
                isFound = True

                'Exit loop
                Exit Do

            End If

            priceRow = priceRow + 1

        Loop

        'If there is no record for price, we should not do anything.
        'If price record for manufacture year is exist, take the price.
        If isFound Then

            'Second, getting the automobile type from Sheet1.

            'Get Automobile Type from sheet
            automobileType = inventorySheet.Range("A" & inventoryRow)

            'Split by space
            splitedValues = Split(Trim(automobileType), " ")

            'Get last word for automobile type
            automobileType = splitedValues(UBound(splitedValues))


            'Third, get the automobile color.

            'Get Automobile Color from sheet.
            automobileColor = inventorySheet.Range("C" & inventoryRow)

            'Split by "-"
            splitedValues = Split(Trim(automobileColor), "-")

            'Get first word for automobile type
            automobileColor = splitedValues(LBound(splitedValues))


            'Reset automobile price.
            automobilePrice = ""

            'Fouth, check type and color and get price
            Select Case automobileType

             Case "Roadster"

                If automobileColor = "Red" Then
                    automobilePrice = priceSheet.Range(redRoadster & priceRow)
                Else
                    automobilePrice = priceSheet.Range(blueRoadster & priceRow)
                End If


             Case "Sedan"

                If automobileColor = "Red" Then
                    automobilePrice = priceSheet.Range(redSedan & priceRow)
                Else
                    automobilePrice = priceSheet.Range(blueSedan & priceRow)
                End If


             Case "Pickup"

                If automobileColor = "Red" Then
                    automobilePrice = priceSheet.Range(redPickup & priceRow)
                Else
                    automobilePrice = priceSheet.Range(bluePickup & priceRow)
                End If

            End Select

            'Fifth, set the price in inventory sheet.
            inventorySheet.Range("I" & inventoryRow) = automobilePrice

        Else

            'Set error for miss.
            inventorySheet.Range("I" & inventoryRow) = "Error"

        End If

        'Increase inventory row
        inventoryRow = inventoryRow + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

Here, my evidence for your problem.

My prepare data for "Sheet1" sheet.

[image]

My prepare data for "FEEDER" sheet.

[image]

After running code, I got this result.

[image]

Have a nice job..!

Comment: First of all, I want to thank everyone who has commented with solutions. Apologies for being slow to respond. 

Nicolas, your code fits the bill. I didn't think of the approach you took which makes plenty of sense when I analyze the coding. I thank you 100X over for the assistance. I will be able to expand on this and complete the task.

Comment: OK...if this is work for you, mark as answer. Thanks..!